# rails css setting background image

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.2

## main.css

```
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url('/assets/background-calculations.png');
}
body #content{
    z-index:5;
    background:url('/assets/handwritten-text.png');
//  background:white;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
body #footer,#header{
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

## index.html.erb is blank

## doubt

when i uncomment `background:white;` in content css its working but when i set the background url its not working , but the same url does not work if i set it for the content div , please help

Comment: Can you provide the full link to the background image? I cannot check your CSS without it :)

Comment: currently talking about development environment, the thing is that when i use the background image for body , its working but for other divs its not working

Comment: for instance
body{
      background:url('/assets/handwritten-text.png');
}
is working but the above is not

Comment: can uou post a demo at jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like;

```
body #content{
    z-index:5;
    background-image:url('/assets/handwritten-text.png');
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/BR9RD/)*** is a working live demo.

Comment: can't you see the blue background image in my fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

if you work in a ruby-on-rails, you have a assets > images. put images in there.

In your stylesheets folder (assets > stylesheets) you have to point to the image, not the folder and image:

```
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url(background-calculations.png);
}
body #content{
    z-index:5;
    background:url(handwritten-text.png);
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
```

Ruby-on-rails knows where your images are